# Get entries using Multi-Select Field as Criteria

Tags: plugin-development, entry, field

When querying for entries, I'm stuck on how to query for "selected" fields.

The query I'm using:

```
$criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Entry);
$criteria->section('athletes');
$criteria->sport = 'tennis';

$players = $criteria->find();
```

This works just fine, but I also need to query further using a field that is a multi-select field. I'd like to do something like:

```
$criteria->tournaments->wimbledon = "selected";
```

This obviously doesn't work though. Does anyone know if this is possible and/or how to accomplish this?